# Grab Android app download count via API call?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way to get the download count of your own Android application via an API?

Play Store doesn't seem to have an API, so I'm guessing it will be a hacky solution.

Comment: Check Andlytics source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any vanilla code / API's for this, so I ended up using the [AppFigures API](https://appfigures.com/reports/date). They have free accounts where you can track up to 5 apps.